# How to change the value in a select with a custom value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sup,

I wanted to make a fancy selector where a user can select his/her gender.
Since the custom select is not very good, more accurately styled to my needs, I have made a custom select that fit my needs.

I placed my custom select underneath the default selector (which is hidden in the application later) and want to change its value according to the value from the custom select.

I created a snippet below:

```js
console.clear();

var el = {};

$('.placeholder').on('click', function (ev) {
  $('.placeholder').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();
});

 $('.list__ul a').on('click', function (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var index = $(this).parent().index();
   var value = $('.list__ul').find('li a').eq(index).html();

   $('.placeholder').text( $(this).text() ).css('opacity', '1');

   console.log(value);

   $('select#gender').val(value);

   $('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).prependTo('.list__ul');
   $('.list__ul').toggle();

 });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap");

:root {
  --bg-main: #f2f2f2;
  --color-main: #404040;
  --ball-color: rgb(66, 73, 168);
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  color: var(--color-main);
  background-color: var(--bg-main);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: clamp(2.4rem, calc(2.4rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.9444)), 3.8rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p,
label {
  font-size: clamp(1.6rem, calc(1.6rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.6667)), 2rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 700;
}

label {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

#gender {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

/** Fancy selector */
.typo,
.list a {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.typo option,
.list a option {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.transition {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: -4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.list ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.list ul .active {
  display: block;
}
.list li {
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:first-child a {
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}
.list a {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: rgba(123, 0, 255, 1);
  position: relative;
}
.list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.list a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
}
.list a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholder {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}
.placeholder:hover {
  color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="gender">Please choose your gender</label>
<select name="gender" id="gender" required="true">
  <option value="Choose" selected="" disabled="">Choose gender</option>
  <option value="1">Man</option>
  <option value="3">Woman</option>
  <option value="5">Non-Binary</option>
</select>

<!-- Just a fancy selector -->
<div class="wrapper typo">Please choose a
  <div class="list"><span class="placeholder">gender</span>
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li><a href="">Man</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Woman</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Non-Binary</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the value from the default select with jQuery using **.val()**, **value = ** but this doesn´t seem to work out for me.

Comment: If you are going to hide the default selector anyway, why create it? Just store the value in a variable.

Comment: @WaliWaqar We´re using formspree to submit the data we collect to our email adresses.

Comment: Well in that case what you are doing wrong is that the values for your options are integers, while the value you are passing through jquery is a string containing the gender type, for which there is no corresponding option element

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the values of the option element are integers (this would require a change in the solution)

Comment: No there is no specific reason for that. I just played around with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value attributes of your option elements did not correspond to what you were passing to the val function. Here is the fixed code:

```js
console.clear();

var el = {};

$('.placeholder').on('click', function(ev) {
  $('.placeholder').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();
});

$('.list__ul a').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  var value = $('.list__ul').find('li a').eq(index).html();

  $('.placeholder').text($(this).text()).css('opacity', '1');

  console.log(value);

  $('select#gender').val(value);

  $('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).prependTo('.list__ul');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();

});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap");
:root {
  --bg-main: #f2f2f2;
  --color-main: #404040;
  --ball-color: rgb(66, 73, 168);
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  color: var(--color-main);
  background-color: var(--bg-main);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: clamp(2.4rem, calc(2.4rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.9444)), 3.8rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p,
label {
  font-size: clamp(1.6rem, calc(1.6rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.6667)), 2rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 700;
}

label {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

#gender {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}


/** Fancy selector */

.typo,
.list a {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.typo option,
.list a option {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.transition {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: -4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.list ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.list ul .active {
  display: block;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.list li:first-child a {
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}

.list a {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: rgba(123, 0, 255, 1);
  position: relative;
}

.list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.list a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
}

.list a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholder {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}

.placeholder:hover {
  color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="gender">Please choose your gender</label>
<select name="gender" id="gender" required="true">
  <option value="Choose" selected="" disabled="">Choose gender</option>
  <option value="Man">Man</option>
  <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
  <option value="Non-Binary">Non-Binary</option>
</select>

<!-- Just a fancy selector -->
<div class="wrapper typo">Please choose a
  <div class="list"><span class="placeholder">gender</span>
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li><a href="">Man</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Woman</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Non-Binary</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not selecting properly because there are no options in the `select` with a value of any of the custom options. Instead, change them so they correspond to the content of the option.

```js
console.clear();

var el = {};

$('.placeholder').on('click', function (ev) {
  $('.placeholder').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();
});

 $('.list__ul a').on('click', function (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var index = $(this).parent().index();
   var value = $('.list__ul').find('li a').eq(index).html();

   $('.placeholder').text( $(this).text() ).css('opacity', '1');

   console.log(value);

   $('select#gender').val(value);

   $('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).prependTo('.list__ul');
   $('.list__ul').toggle();

 });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap");

:root {
  --bg-main: #f2f2f2;
  --color-main: #404040;
  --ball-color: rgb(66, 73, 168);
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  color: var(--color-main);
  background-color: var(--bg-main);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: clamp(2.4rem, calc(2.4rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.9444)), 3.8rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p,
label {
  font-size: clamp(1.6rem, calc(1.6rem + ((1vw - 0.48rem) * 1.6667)), 2rem);
  min-height: 0vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 700;
}

label {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

#gender {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

/** Fancy selector */
.typo,
.list a {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.typo option,
.list a option {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.transition {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: -4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.list ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.list ul .active {
  display: block;
}
.list li {
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:first-child a {
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}
.list a {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: rgba(123, 0, 255, 1);
  position: relative;
}
.list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.list a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(176, 102, 255, 1);
}
.list a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholder {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(125, 64, 191, 1);
}
.placeholder:hover {
  color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="gender">Please choose your gender</label>
<select name="gender" id="gender" required="true">
  <option value="Choose" selected="" disabled="">Choose gender</option>
  <option value="Man">Man</option>
  <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
  <option value="Non-Binary">Non-Binary</option>
</select>

<!-- Just a fancy selector -->
<div class="wrapper typo">Please choose a
  <div class="list"><span class="placeholder">gender</span>
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li><a href="">Man</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Woman</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Non-Binary</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```